# Multiple definitions exist for class

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using Kohana framework which allows for multiple class definitions (in application and system subfolders). I'm using PhpStorm as an IDE which gives me messages `multiple definitions exist for class`. Is there any way to tell PhpStorm which class definition is correct?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've found a possible solution to my problem - I can `mark file as plain`

Comment: Yeah I think this is a bug in PHPStorm.  Running PhpStorm 8 my software was viewing the class reference from a different *project* which is why there were multiple definitions.  I deleted the old project and the error is gone.

Comment: @Acyra, No, the same behaviour is in PHPStorm 8.

Comment: It's a solution, but the worst one here by far. Kuba's suggestion works.

Comment: This is the best solution for me. If I exclude the directory of tests that has a duplicate mock class definition, I can't fully grep the codebase in intellij and will miss instances of things in the excluded directory. Much better to mark the file as text so its still indexed and searchable by intellij, then mark it as source code when necessary. It still wont get treated as source but atleast its greppable; gotta grep to refactor PHP anyways.

Comment: I think in some cases this could be the best solution.  I came here because package nesbot/carbon defined the interface JsonSerializable for backwards compatibility with PHP versions that don't have it.  They wrapped the definition with `if(! interface_exists('JsonSerializable'))` so it didn't clash.  But PHPStorm didn't know that.  I just marked their redefinition of the interface as plain text, which removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 106):

> Is there any way to tell PhpStorm which class definition is correct?

You cannot, unfortunately.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17646 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

ATM you either just ignore the under-waving .. or you can configure that inspection to not to report such cases (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Undefined | Undefined class`, it has `Don't report multiple class declaration potential problems` checkbox).

Even with that inspection configured, IDE will still ask you what class declaration to jump to (and this is correct behaviour as IDE does not know if you want to see the original implementation or implement your own).

---

The only other way is to ensure that there is only one class with the same name in the project. For that you may use:

- Mark whole folder as excluded
- Mark individual file as Plain Text

Both are available via content menu in Project View and applicable to project files only (e.g. will be unavailable or will do nothing useful if tried to apply in Library scope).

Comment: What about autosuggest feature? It does not work either when there are multiple definitions of a class.

Comment: @Meglio Yeah - that's how IDE behaves -- if more than one class with the same name then it behaves weird. The best -- exclude duplicates from the project -- either whole folder (Mark as Excluded) or individual files (Mark as Plain Text). I guess https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17646 would be the right ticket to watch after...

Comment: For PhpStorm 2018, option is at ```Settings | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Undefined | 
 Undefined class | Don't report multiple class declaration potential problems```

Comment: @AndyWhite removing the information does not resolve the problem at all, it just hides it. In some cases autocomplete won't work so the only thing that happens is that you dont get infromed about this behavior. You should find the duplicated files/folders and ignore them in your project settings. See my Post. By the way he had this information you said already in his post. :)

Comment: PhpStorm 2022 - `Settings | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Undefined symbols | Multiple class declarations`

Comment: I had this problem with JsonException, All I have done is excluding Plolyfils and dev packages (rector, phpstan) By marking them as excluded

Comment: How php then knows which class to use if there are multiple definitions? Somehow it knows, why then same way IDE cannot know?

Comment: @Darius.V *"How php then knows which class to use if there are multiple definitions? Somehow it knows, why then same way IDE cannot know?"* PHP allows to have only ONE class with the same name (FQN) loaded at the same time. And framework/your code may decide WHICH one to use/load **during runtime**.

Comment: @Darius.V Imagine you have `index1.php` that uses `MyClass` from `v1/MyClass.php` and `index2.php` that uses `MyClass` from `v2/MyClass.php`. You also have `shared.php` that is included by both of the index files. **Question** -- WHICH CLASS `shared.php` will be using?

Comment: @LazyOne the one which is imported? So you mean many logic has to be executed for it to know which one will be used and that might be too heavy for IDE?

Comment: @Darius.V So that's what I'm asking -- **which one will be imported** when I'm in a `shared.php` file? You cannot know that for sure... because it will be known only during runtime, based on which file (index1 or index2) was executed. Looking at the issue in this SO Question, it's Kohana framework (dead now AFAIK) -- it was selecting the file to load based on file existence: if a file was present then it was loading class from one location; if absent -- from another.

Comment: Kohana dead but there are still projects using it :D So IDE could check the file existance but only question if it will work fast enough.

Comment: @Darius.V This is Kohana-specific behavior. This is NOT the widely-used practice. The IDE core sadly does not provide any special support for any of the PHP frameworks (as in "check for the class here first and then there if it does not exist"). All of such stuff is provided by framework-specific plugins. Even Laravel, the most popular one right now, you need to have 3rd party plugin for the framework magic (Facades, routing and other stuff). You want a stuff that depends on the actual run time results / follows some special rules -- find/write a plugin that can supply it to the IDE.

Comment: I have noticed this practice also by PhpUnit - for phps unit classes it shows multiple class definitions. Maybe it is not sad, if that would cause performance issues, betterm aybe to use plugin if such exists.

Answer (score 32):

You should just ignore the complete cache folder.

- Go to Settings > Directories
- Choose `var\cache`
- Set it to 'Excluded'

From: https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/301

Comment: With symfony3 like the guy from the link provided say, the autocompletion for service won't work anymore

Comment: With Symfony, I work in applications and libraries at the same time. Call them projects `p1` and `p2` respectively. `p2` is accessible both from `projects/p2` and `projects/p1/vendors/xavi-montero/p2` via symlink. When editing some classes (for example a Symfony Controller) in `p1` autocomplete did not work. Reason: as both have vendors installed, they conflicted. I just excluded `projects/p1/vendor/xavi-montero/p2/vendor`. I can now autocomplete my own classes from `p2` when editing `p1` but conflicts disappeared as the "second" vendors is ignored while the "first" is not excluded.

Comment: This solution works perfect if composer symlink local packages for development from `packages/*` into `public/app/plugins/*` folder.

Answer (score 14):

As variant you can turn off inspection only for specific class. Put cursor inside underwaved class name, then `Alt+Enter` → `Inspection options` → `Supress for statement`

PHPStorm adds

```
/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
```

above class declaration and class name is not underwaved anymore.

Comment: Works, but this is an ugly solution. Everywhere annotations.

Answer (score 11):

I've been around the web everywhere and not a single option worked for me... I've been struggling for months with it, and today I found a solution, so if none of the above works for you, try redefining the PHP Include Path List. under Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP, make sure only the folders containing paths to source used by your project or application is configured.

My scenario is that I do a lot of package development, and while my packages are all in one project, they are also "symlinked" in "vendor" in my composer configuration, so there is duplicated code found by PHPStorm, in the vendor folder and my packages folder. Similarly, if include paths are duplicated, or paths are configured to find code outside of your project, which is already part of the project, it will also find multiple definitions. So, excluding the symlinked folders in vendor, allows PHPStorm to only find one copy of the source to my packages, and if my packages contain vendor folders of their own, they will also show up as duplicated definitions. Remove anything in the Include Path list where it may find dipplication

Comment: This helped me, it turns out my `www` project was referencing my `api` project both via `whatever/myproject/api/src` and via `vendor/myproject/api`, which caused most classes to get the "Multiple definitions exist for class" -warning, regardless of any `use ...` -statements. Drove me nuts until I looked closely on the listed paths in `Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> PHP`. Deleting the first one and editing the second one to `vendor/myproject/api/src` seems to have done the trick.

Comment: This solution worked best for me; I had this problem because Symfony's PHPUnit bridge uses a symlink for the `phpunit` source and so PHPStorm picked up two sources.

I was able to fix it by going into Languages & Frameworks > PHP and only specifying one of the two PHPUnit folders as the source.

Answer (score 9):

### Prolog

Guess there are several ways to solve this problem. Actually, it's just a warning and it says that phpstorm can't provide you with autocompletion so you have to work a bit harder :D

I had the same problem as many others here and solved it by ignoring unwanted.

---

### Scenario

Had a git project with a vendor-folder after composer install. Also, there is a `my-project.phar` in this project that also contains some vendor stuff and this caused my warnings.

---

### Solution

`File > Preferences|Settings > Directories`
There you have to possibility to exclude files and folders. In my case it's the `.phar` so it's a **"file"** and you can add it at the bottom of the settings-window.

[image: sample]

PHPStorm will no longer see duplicates.

> This is very project-specific and I guess most people have to find their own solution but pointing to this may help to find the problem easier.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 8):

Just some addition to the  Andy White's comment:

> Settings | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Undefined |   Undefined class | Don't report multiple class declaration potential problems

I really couldn't find this config and thought it was no there now, but this is still there, but very well hidden)

It is a little counterintuitive and inconspicuous, but the needed checkbox is in the right panel, and appears only if you click on the `Undefined class` row:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your project there are multiple definitions for the same class. I discovered I had backup copies in my project which caused this warning. I removed the backups from my Project (a good idea anyway) and it fixed the error.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you created the other definition, but if you or anyone has this issue due to calling `class_alias()`, then you can solve this issue quickly.

Consider

```
class_alias(
    'The\AliasClass',
    'My\RealClass',
    true
);
```

and

```
class_alias(
    'The\AliasClass',
    'My\Real'.'Class', // <-- break up the string
    true
);
```

With the latter, PhpStorm will not pick up the `My\RealClass` and your "multiple definition" warning will cease. This is an ancient JavaScript trick to embed HTML in a string literal, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

This warning has annoyed me for a long time. I believe the answers here saying there is a duplicate file somewhere is correct. The reason I am getting the warnings are due to the autocomplete file to give phpStorm a hint on how to find codeIgniter functions. If you are doing this also that is the reason for some of the warnings. The autocomplete file makes phpStorm think there are two different definitions. However, I like autocomplete more than I dislike the warnings so I guess I have to live with them.

This is the autocomplete I'm referring to:
[IntelliJ IDEA 12 not finding CodeIgniter classes, throwing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424828/intellij-idea-12-not-finding-codeigniter-classes-throwing-errors)

Answer (score 2):

## Alternatives that work after a fashion, but aren't so good

- marking the file B you don't want to be used by autocomplete as "plain" or excluded, leaving file A active: this will disable notifications in the file C, **but will also make autocompletion no longer work for whatever is in file B**. So if somewhere else you use something that's rightly in B, and maybe there you want to exclude A from autocompletion, you can't do that.
- disable the inspection: this will also disable undefined class warnings, so if I make any typos in any class name, I'll only discover this after deployment (or from the fact that autocomplete stops working for that object).
- "Don't report multiple class declaration potential problems" - this is very nearly good, but I don't like having "potential problems" ignored; what if I create a class with an unwittingly duplicated name that is in use somewhere else? Granted that I'll catch it (or phpunit will), but *still*.

## The best I've found so far

The way to go for now, at least until a more focused configuration is available for PHPStorm (e.g. "Alternative Classes"), is to mark those notifications - and only those - as ignorable:

```
/* @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
/**
 * Verify an existing contract. Requires agent and supervisor.
 *
 * @param array   $data
 * @param Cliente $cli
 * @param User    $age
 * @param User    $sup
 * @return Contratto
 */
private function contratto(
    array $data,
    /* @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
    Cliente $cli,
    /* @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
    User $age,
    /* @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
    User $sup
) {
```

Note that to disable notifications in the PHPDoc comment I had to add a directive before the comment; this **did not disable** the notifications for the three parameters.

In the future, I wish to be able to specify those in PHPStorm as

```
 * @param array                 $data    raw data for the contract
 * @param \local\foobar\Cliente $cli     customer opening the contract

private function contratto(
    array $data,
    /*\local\foobar\*/Cliente $cli,
```

or better still, explicitly use a new PHPdoc tag such as "@replaces". So PHPStorm would know that my class is the one *not* replaced. I'll also have to decorate my `use`'s to specify the class I'll be actually using.

And run a search for "@noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection" throughout my code.

## Another way

The above problems stem from the fact that I have a "master" Customer class which is overridden by a "local" modification for the *foobar* client, whose Customers have (say) a special method.

The "correct" way of doing this should be to declare a FoobarCustomer which is only employed by foobar's code, and is a child class of Customer. **Of course this is only possible if the child class is in my code, not in the framework's**, and also I may need some methods in the parent class to be `protected` rather than `private`, which may make this solution either impossible or needful of [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php):

```
/**
 * Verify an existing contract. Requires agent and supervisor.
 *
 * @param array         $data
 * @param FoobarCliente $cli
 * @param FoobarUser    $age
 * @param FoobarUser    $sup
 * @return Contratto
 */
private function contratto(array $data, FoobarCliente $cli, FoobarUser $age...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't use PHP anylonger. upvoted anyways

Comment: point one is not true. If you have multiple definitions of a class, autocomplete cant work because phpstorm doesnt know which file to use. If you disable one, autocomplete works again because phpstom knows the correct file now! And its truely the best solution because it does exactly whats expected. :)

Comment: @Dwza I expressed myself badly, I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and it was quite annoying one. I was using Yii2 framework and as it turned out at the end I have accidentally created en extra "vendor" folder and composer.json in the root of the project (not in the root of the app) so I ended up with that warning as phpStorm was confused which extension folder is the right one.
I've deleted extra vendor folder and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try delete duplicate declared libraries

**Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Include Path**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in my case by removing a more specific entry in my composer.json that included code by another more general entry

Answer (score 0):

If you create a backup folder and copy a class to [backup] folder, this issue can be occurred for that class.
If you have similar case, just do the followings to fix this issue:

- Right click on [backup] folder in project window,
- Then, select **Mark Directory as** > **Excluded**

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm add in Class.

`<?php`

```
/** @noinspection PhpMultipleClassDeclarationsInspection */
```

`namespace ...`