# PhpStorm (Laravel 8) all standart eloquent methods not found on one model, but available on another (no code hinting)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpstorm

(I have checked previous posts regarding this situation)

On the pictures below you see code from the **SAME** file "StripeController.php"

Both Classes/Models (**StripeEvent** and **Transaction**) **extends Model**, has

**namespace App\Models**, and uses:

**use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;**

**use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;**

This line is **NOT** present in any of those Models (**use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder**)

No DOC blocs are present in both Classes/Models.

Here PhpStorm says that "firstWhere" method not found on **StripeEvent** model:
[image]

But on previous line (in the same file) with **Transaction** model PhpStorm finds this method:
[image]

I tried to create other new models, but problem remains the same. Methods are recognized by PhpStorm only for old/previously created models, but NOT recognized for new ones.

I suspect that there might be some config or helper cache that should be re-generated.

Any ideas how to fix it and make PhpStorm code hint and not underline eloquent methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [Laravel Idea](https://laravel-idea.com/) in your PhpStorm, you need to click "Laravel / Generate Helper Code" in the top menu. Also, if you have [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package in your laravel app, you can use the following commands:

```bash
php artisan ide-helper:generate
php artisan ide-helper:models
php artisan ide-helper:meta
```

Comment: Yea, I use Laravel Idea and "Generate Helper Code" solved the situation. You also mentioned Laravel IDE Helper. Can it be used together with Laravel Idea, i mean will there be no conflicts? Thank you for advice.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't use both simultaneously, so I cannot say for sure. My guess is it doesn't lead to a significant problem. Maybe you would get a "Multiple definitions exist for class" notice in the code analysis of PhpStorm (If you get the notice, you can look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066665/multiple-definitions-exist-for-class)).